# syntax for data frames to use for 2 options

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe, df. One of the column is Text. I want to search the dataframe where the text contains `ABC`.

Hence, I write the code:

```
df["Text"].str.contains("ABC")
```

Now, I want to search which text contains `ABC` or `XYZ`.

What will be the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `|` pipe is what you need

```
DF['Text'].str.contains('ABC|XYZ')
```

Comment: I think you wanted `DF['Text'].str.contains('ABC|XYZ')` because `'ABC' | 'XYZ'` gives "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'"

Comment: that's a very big yes. oops, thanks for pointing that out (didn't test that since I was at my phone)

Answer (score 0):

```
DF['Text'].str.contains('ABC') | DF['Text'].str.contains('XYZ')
```